# How to create public subnet with different zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I create 2 Subnets with Cloudformation, but both are created in the same ZONE. How can I create them in a separate zone? I don't want to give zone manually. I set it according to the zone I am in.

**YAML file for Subnet1**

```
  Subnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    DependsOn: NginxVPC
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref NginxVPC
      CidrBlock: !Ref Subnet1CidrBlock
      AvailabilityZone: 
        Fn::Select: 
          - 0
          - Fn::GetAZs: ""
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Subnet1
```

Comment: `Fn::GetAZs` results in a list of AZs. Use index 0, 1, ... as needed to ensure subnets are in different AZs.

Comment: That is good point. I missed that. Thanks.